# Maven plugin configuration vs properties

Tags: java, maven

What are pros and cons of configuring Maven plugins through `properties` as oppose to `configuration`?

For example, `maven-compiler-plugin` documentation explicitly shows configuring `source` and `target` as 
shown below, presumably going even further with `pluginManagement`.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Wouldn't it be more succinct to use [user properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) instead, with no dependency on specific version?

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, many parameters of many goals do not have any associated user property, so can only be set via `<configuration>`.

For those which do have a user property (such as these examples), it depends. A few user properties are specifically coördinated between multiple goals or even plugins, as @khmarbaise points out.

User properties can be overridden from the command line, as @kdoteu points out, which is useful in certain cases—though very likely not for Java source/target level which would normally be intrinsic to the project (something you would change in a versioned commit alongside source file changes). User properties can also be overridden from external profiles such as in `settings.xml`, which is occasionally important.

On the other hand, plugin configuration is more explicit: it is expressly associated with a particular goal (or all goals in a plugin using the same parameter name). Some IDEs can offer code completion. You need not worry about accidentally having some other unrelated plugin interpret a property name (though plugin authors try to use unique-looking prefixes for most user property names). Surprisingly, Maven (3.8.1) will not fail the build if you mistype the parameter name, however—it will just quietly ignore the extra element.

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the **properties** druing build time with commandline parameters. And you can use them in multimodule projects. 
So wie are using them to configure findbugs or some urls for deploying.

Answer (score 0):

There are some properties which are automatically taken by plugins. One for example are the given target/source information. An other is the `project.build.sourceEncoding` which is taken into account of several plugins like maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin etc. So it makes sense to use properties which reduces the size and number of your configurations for plugins.